# What does mean by "stand on each other's necks" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Sentence belongs to The *Giver (2014)* movie:

> Giver: I've cried felt true sorrow, I've sung, danced. I've felt real joy.
>
> Chief Elder: Then you should know better than anyone.You have seen children starve.
>   You've seen people **stand on each other's necks**.

What does mean by "stand on each other's necks" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'***To stand on someone's neck***' means:

> *To be victimized by someone, who is controlling everything that you do and thereby preventing you to act or function normally.*

What would happen if somebody literally stands on your neck? Or let's assume that someone's got a tight grip around your neck. You'll suffocate, you find it very hard to breathe.

Similarly, when someone prevents you to do something that you naturally do, and you feel like you are being controlled or manipulated by that person, to such an extend that you cannot even perform your basic activities or actions, you could use this phrase.

In the given context,

> You've seen people stand on each other's necks.

This means that, in this world, it is quite common to see people holding back others, for selfish reasons. 
People tend to hinder other people's life and activities just so that they can go ahead with their lives, much smoother without any competition.

If you take an example where there is one job vacancy and 10 people are eligible for it. Apart from trying harder themselves, they tend to do things that may stop the others from having a chance at getting the job. They tend to eliminate their competition rather than strengthen their own chance.